# Show attribute value using its id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

In my application, I am grouping my objects by an ID. At the moment, I can only display the ID, but I would like to display the attribute value.

A Fixture `belongs_to` a tournament and a tournament `has_many` fixtures.

Controller

```
def index
  @fixtures = Fixture.all
  @tournament_fixture = @fixtures.group_by {|f| f.tournament_id}
end
```

View

```
<% @tournament_fixture.sort.each do |tourn_name, fixture| %>
     <%= tourn_name %>
        <% fixture.each do |f| %>
          <td><%= f.home_team %></td>
          <td><%= f.away_team %></td>
          <td><%= f.kickoff_time %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

How can I get

```
<%= tourn_name %>
```

to display its corresponding value that is in its `:name column`?

At the moment in my view for example i get this returned

```
<tbody>
        2
        <tr>
          <td>Tournament Name</td>
          <td>Team 1</td>
          <td>Team 2</td>
          <td>2000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC</td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="/fixtures/1">view</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

The 2 needs to be the value in the :name column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend grouping by `tournament` instead:

```
@tournament_fixture = @fixtures.group_by(&:tournament)
```

And then iterate using:

```
<% @tournament_fixture.sort.each do |tournament, fixture| %>
  <%= tournament.name %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the whole object much like you can get the id like this:

```
def index
  @fixtures = Fixture.includes(:tournaments).all
  @tournament_fixture = @fixtures.group_by {|f| f.tournament.name}
end
```

The `id` is still available as either `f.tournament_id` or `f.tournament.id`, should you still need it but I just figured you'd rather group by its name directly. I simply added an `includes` statement to also load the referenced Tournament objects with your fixtures in one go. Otherwise, Rails would load the tournaments only when you access them one by one.

As an alternative, you could load the Tournaments, including all their the fixtures instead and iterate over the tournaments like this:

**Controller**

```
def index
  @tournaments = Tournament.includes(:fixtures).all
end
```

**View**

```
<% @tournaments.each do |tournament| %>
  <%= tournament.name %>
    <% tournament.fixtures.each do |f| %>
      <td><%= f.home_team %></td>
      <td><%= f.away_team %></td>
      <td><%= f.kickoff_time %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It seems a bit more natural to me and you don't need to iterate over all fixtures to map them by their tournament.

Comment: ok i see what you saying now, when infact i just figured out I could do this in the controller..... tournament_fixture = fixtures.group_by {|f| f.tournament.name}, but is this a bad practice?

Comment: If you are using an `include` in your fixtures, it's alright I guess - otherwise Rails would load the tournament for each fixture with a single statement. Depending on the number of fixtures, it may take a (short) while though. Keep that in mind when your controller method gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the fixtures in the right order. There is no need to group then in memory. Remember to include the `tournaments` to avoid `N+1` queries.

```
# controller
def index
  @fixtures = Fixture.order(:tournament_id).includes(:tournaments).all
end
```

Loading in the right order in the controller makes the view simpler. For the tournament's  name just use the association between `Fixture` and `Tournament`.

```
# view
<% @fixtures.each do |fixture| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= fixture.tournament.name %></td>
    <td><%= fixture.home_team %></td>
    <td><%= fixture.away_team %></td>
    <td><%= fixture.kickoff_time %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```